# Tomcat 7 - write in symlink directory

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I'm trying to unzip in a directory symlinked in my WebApp and get this error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/_Apps/xxxxx.txt (Permission denied)

**_Apps** is my symlink (owned by tomcat, 777) and refers to a directory owned by tomcat (755)

My tomcat version is **7**

I've put **allowLinking="true"** in my app **context** tag (plus override="true").

Any idea of what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues here, some related to your question, some to best practice:

- You shouldn't upload any files to your webapp at runtime: They'll get overwritten with the next deployment (and will be lost), plus you open yourself up to uploads like `attack.jsp` - containing code that might end up running server side, under the account that tomcat is running as
- Really, you should write to a different directory
- That will make your issue go away.
- In order to temporarily check what causes the issue:

  - Validate which user tomcat is running as
  - Validate that this user account has write access to the directory - to be more confident: Validate this through the linked directory *and* through the underlying directory, natively without using the link. (You can `sudo -u tomcat /bin/bash` to manually try)
  - Check, which file system the directory is on (it might be mounted read-only)
- Once you've finished validating (or even before that, reluctant that you can work on a higher priority - security relevant - issue): Go back to the beginning of the list and change your implementation. Upload to a different folder.